# Convert WebDAV to FTP

Tags: ftp, webdav, ibm-datapower

I am wondering if it is possible to convert WebDAV to FTP.

I have already found that the POST and GET methods can be parsed into an FTP url that sends or retrieves the files (in my case, using IBM DataPower). Although I managed to get both methods working, I seem to have problems getting a listing of the files in that FTP folder using WebDAV.

Could anyone give me a hint on what should travel on both request and response for the PROPFIND method? (DP v7 already supports non-standard HTTP methods)

From what I saw: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142960(v=exchg.65).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142960%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) it seems like XML is travelling to and from, so I might be able to do something with it, am I right?

Thanks in advance :)

Regards!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but milton.io (a java based webdav framework) includes an FTP adapter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes indeed it's XML.

The format is defined in [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-14.20).

You have some help in this SO question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144148/example-of-a-minimal-request-response-cycle-for-webdav).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I consider the link a bonus (although I have a hard time beliving IETF will change the RFC link structure) - the answer is RFC 4918, which is master definition of the WebDAV format (at least the parts asked for). I would rather not copy/paste the entire specs to SO.